# Flink backpressure in stream split

Tags: flink-streaming

## Background

We have the following Flink execution plan:
[image]

`Operator 2`:

1. Has low parallelism. Each key has many records.
2. Gets ***no records*** at all.

## The problem

We see backpressure on `Operator 1`.

## The question

Is it possible that `Operator 2` is causing backpressure on `Operator 1` although it gets ***no records*** at all?